# Fails on: /opt/lampp/xampp security

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

## Problem explanation

I've just installed LAMPP with PHP 7.1.1, when I try using from console
`/opt/lampp/xampp security` the program asks me the following question:

> XAMPP:  Quick security check... 
>  XAMPP:  Your XAMPP pages are
>   NOT secured by a password. 
>  XAMPP: Do you want to set a
>   password? [yes]

Then I type yes, I input twice the password and it returns the following error:

> /opt/lampp/share/xampp/checkapache: line 41:
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/.htaccess: No such file or directory 
>  cp:
>   cannot stat '/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/.htaccess': No such file or
>   directory 
> cp: cannot stat '/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/.htaccess': No such
>   file or directory 
>  chmod: cannot access 
>   '/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/.htaccess': No such file or directory 
>  chmod:
>   cannot access '/opt/lampp/htdocs/webalizer/.htaccess': No such file or
>   directory 
>  chmod: cannot access '/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/.htaccess': No
>   such file or directory

Line 41 stands for `cat << EOT > $XAMPP_ROOT/htdocs/xampp/.htaccess` and it's before with the following content:

```
    cat << EOT > $XAMPP_ROOT/htdocs/xampp/.htaccess
AuthName "xampp user"                 
AuthType Basic    
AuthUserFile $XAMPP_ROOT/lib/xampp.users
require valid-user                    
EOT
```

## What I've already tried

I've already searched through Google and Stackoverflow and I've found these posts:

[.htaccess not working on localhost with xampp](http://ps://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162214/htaccess-not-working-on-localhost-with-xampp)

[apachefriends forums](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/)

Finally I've searched on Google and I've read read this article about the security option:
(link removed due I'm new and I don't have 10 reputation)

In that article all was fine, and it doesn't say anything about the error I got.

I've also tried creating my own .htaccess file with the content listed above (replacing $XAMPP_ROOT with /opt/lampp). It didn't work even when I gave it executing permission `chmod u+x /opt/lampp/xampp/.htaccess` (I know it doesn't have sense due is not a script or a runnable, but I was trying).

## My question

My question is how shall I solve the problem so I can set a XAMPP pages password.

## Solution - Solved

The paths I got were bad. I had to use the command `find /opt/lampp -name "webalizer"` and others to know the correct paths. Here you have how I solved it:

1. Execute the command `touch /opt/lampp/.htaccess`
2. Open this file /opt/lampp/share/xampp/checkapache with your favorite text editor and move to line 41 (note: it's required being root).
3. Replace from lines 41 to 51 with the following instructions:

   ```
       cat << EOT > $XAMPP_ROOT/.htaccess
   AuthName "xampp user"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile $XAMPP_ROOT/lib/xampp.users
   require valid-user
   EOT
       cp $XAMPP_ROOT/.htaccess $XAMPP_ROOT/htdocs/webalizer/.htaccess
       cp $XAMPP_ROOT/.htaccess $XAMPP_ROOT/phpmyadmin/.htaccess
       echo "xampp:$word" > $XAMPP_ROOT/lib/xampp.users
       chmod a+r $XAMPP_ROOT/.htaccess $XAMPP_ROOT/htdocs/webalizer/.htaccess $XAMPP_ROOT/phpmyadmin/.htaccess
       chmod a+r $XAMPP_ROOT/lib/xampp.users
   ```
4. Save the changes and execute the command `/opt/lampp/xampp security`, it should work now. **The command can throw a error if you've already removed the default files (the folder webalizer)**

Comment: The paths are inconsistent. XAMPP is trying with this path: `/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/` and you're using this path: `/opt/lampp/xampp/`. Which one is correct?

Comment: The first path stands for the default files and the second one stands for the root of the lampp program (that is really /opt/lampp/)

Comment: Scotts-MacBook-Pro-2:~ scottlydon$ touch /opt/lampp/.htaccess
touch: /opt/lampp/.htaccess: No such file or directory